# Finding aggregated sum of each department using python

Tags: python

I have departments and salary in each department. I want to find sum of each department.

`10,20,30,40,10` are the department_id.
`1000,2000,1000` are the salary of each department.

```
departments=[[10,1000],[20,2000],[30,1000],[30,4000],[10,3000]]
groupDict={}
newDict={}
for i in departments:
    groupDict["dept_id"]=i[0]
    groupDict["salary"]=i[1]
    print(groupDict)
    newDict.update(groupDict)
    
print(newDict)
```

I wanted to find sum by making dictionary like this:

```
groupDict={
    {
        dept_id:10,
        salary:1000
    },
    {
        dept_id:10,
        salary:1000 
    }
}
```

I updated dictionary using `newDict.update(groupDict)` but its not working. Is there any better way to find sum for each department rahter than using dictionary?

My expected output is

```
[[10,4000],[20,2000],[30,5000]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have duplicate keys in a dictionary.

You may however directly sum the values for each department id:

```
for i in departments:
    if i[0] in groupDict:
        groupDict[i[0]] += i[1]
    else
        groupDict[i[0]] = i[1]
```

(you may avoid the `if` - `else` by using a `defaultdict(int)` instead of an ordinary `dict`)

Comment: i tried to see print(groupDict)  but it is displaying {'dept_id': 10, 'salary': 3000} while using your code

Comment: I accidentally left the `groupDict["dept_id"]=i[0]` line. Now I edited the answer. Anyhow it should have worked all the same